# What does it mean when df returns the same mount over and over?

Tags: catalina, smb, automount, autofs, command-line

I am on the latest MacOS Catalina 10.15.5.  I have the following `automount` setup:

#### /etc/auto_master:

```
/- auto_smb -nosuid,timeout=35
```

#### /etc/auto_smb

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/myuser/Volumes/mymount -fstype=smbfs,soft,rw ://user:pass@smbhost/share
```

When I run `df -h` command, it shows the following duplicated over and over:

```
map auto_smb          0Bi 0Bi 0Bi 100% 0 0 100% /Users/myuser/Volumes/mymount
//user@smbhost/share 4.4Ti 3.1Ti 1.3Ti 71% 3341027482 1397355092 71% /Users/myuser/Volumes/mymount
```

Every now and then there is a new duplicate in the output.  Right now there're 100+ duplicates but the mounted disk works fine.

This problem seems to be recent as I've only begun experiencing this in the past month or so.  Even though the mount works fine, sometimes it seems to be a little slower to access than it should be...

Why is automount generating so many duplicates (or `df` just reporting them), is this an actual concern (I imagine it should be) and what can I do to prevent this from happening?

I have confirmed that internet speed gets slower as there are more connections.  To reset this I need to remove the `auto_smb` part and `diskutil unmount force //user@smbhost/share` and/or `sudo automount -vc`.

The logs in MacOS Console are showing kernel errors:

```
smb2fs_smb_cmpd_query: smb2fs_smb_ntcreatex failed 13
```

Comment: Do you have access to the logs in the server that’s getting mounted recursively?

Comment: searching the macOS logs, I am seeing a bunch of `smb2fs_smb_cmpd_query: smb2fs_smb_ntcreatex failed 13`